# Extend an Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

Here is my situations, I use this attribute `MyAttrAttribute` all over my codebase, I would now like to give it the property such that any place that I use `[MyAttr]`, it also applies a third party attribute `[TheirAttr]`.

Of course, I could do a find a replace across my code to extend the attribute, but is there a way to modify `MyAttrAttribute` to apply the third party attribute as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could derive `MyAttrAttribute` from `TheirAttrAttribute`, and then [`Attribute.GetCustomAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7s8054x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method should work with both types:

> ```
> public static Attribute GetCustomAttribute(
>     Assembly element,
>     Type attributeType
> )
> ```
>
> ....
> *attributeType*
>     Type: System.Type
>     The type, or a base type, of the custom attribute to search for.

Comment: This would only work if `TheirAttrAttribute` isn't `sealed`. If `TheirAttrAttribute` follows [this code quality rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1813) then it won't work.